# MapKit - drawing lines between 2 pins

Tags: objective-c

How can I draw lines between 2 pins on the MapView?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `MKPolyline` class. You can add it to a map view with the `MKMapView` method `-addOverlay:`.